# Microsoft scr***ed my Eclipse preferences: how to recover?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

I have not typical issue: namely I installed VisualStudio Community edition from official Microsoft page and this s**t totally damaged my laptop (it first changed some system settings without my consent, later computer got not responsive at all)my laptop - I was forced to reset OS to factory settings (Windows 8.1 64b) as no other repair attempts worked - thank you, friends from Redmond! One of weirdest things is that this software changed my Eclipse preferences and the problem still persists: background in Eclipse is not dark but black and code is very hard to read. When I go to Window->Preferences->General and change it to default, then theme gets changed only for the file that is currently open(?).After restart of Eclipse the black motive is back. Moreover, when I click any line, it gets highlighted in black - as if there was an additional display pattern deeper 'under the skin'.I know that a screenshot would be more informative but I don't think it can be attached here.

What may shed some light on the issue is that, when I go in Eclipse to Window->Preferences->Appearance I am presented with following themes to choose from:
%theme.dark, %theme.classic etc. No idea what the % sign mean.
How can I get normal default theme permamently? - perhaps it would suffice to delete some preferences file but I am no very adept in the Eclipse staff and not sure what can be safely removed -just don't want to spoil it more than it already is. I am using Eclipse Mars,located in C:\Users\myUsername\java-mars\eclipse, if this matters.

Eclipse is my main working tool for next couple of weeks before I move to IntelliJ and the issue is really onerous for me. Anyone could help, please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine how Visual Studio could break eclipse, maybe some path conflict, but VS has no idea where your eclipse is.  Maybe opening the same project in the workspaces with both and there were some overwrites? IDK.

Eclipse has no dependencies other than JAVA_HOME (or finding java on the path).

That said, workspace settings are stored in /.metadata folder.  You can safely blow this away.  Depending on how you have your projects organized, you may need to reimport your projects (I am assuming you are using a code repo) so this shouldn't be a problem.

If that doesn't work, blow away the java-mars/ folder tree and unzip a clean version.  NOTE: If you do this and open the existing (broken) workspace you will pick up the existing (broken) settings.

Comment: Deletion of .metadata did the job! Many, many thanks - you saved my file!!!   I wonder how guys from MS can go sleep with clear conscience when they launch products with such side effects.

Comment: Excellent! I am glad it worked.  If you'd be so kind, please accept the answer (green check box).